# Full Text search returns duplicate keys

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, full-text-search

I have a search like the example below. The problem is that the result returns a key multiple times if the term "beach" is in myTextColumn multiple times, for example "I went to the beach because the beach is cool". I need it to be returned only once.

The database server is Microsoft SQL 2005

```
  SELECT DISTINCT          
    Src.[Key] AS MyID
  FROM            
    CONTAINSTABLE(MyTable, myTextColumn, N'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,beach )',500) Src
  ORDER BY 
    MyID
```

Comment: Have you tried SELECT TOP 1 Src.[Key]? - Untested

Comment: TOP 1 returns only one record. I need top 500 as specified, just not duplicate keys. Looks like this type of search ignores the DISTINCT keyword.

Comment: All I can do is upvote your answer. I would like to know too

Comment: `group by Src.[Key]` instead of `distinct`?

Comment: I can't seem to duplicate your behavior.  I get a unique row even if the column contains multiple instances of the search word.  Only the `RANK` is lower.  I guess the first place to look is how you set up your FULLTEXT catalog and index.

Comment: @Andreas, I tried group by Src.[Key] but still got dups. It sounded promising but no cigar.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was caused by a bad full text search index. It had to be rebuilt with "do not track changes", and the correct word breaker for the given language.